# Subquery help in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, subquery

Hi can someone help me how to write the below query in LINQ as I'm new to LINQ

```
select * from Employee where employeeid = 'E101'
or empdept = (select dept from departments where deptid = 'D101')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: from e in employee where (e.employeeid  == 'E101'))
        || e.empdept == (from d in department  where d.deptid == 'D101' ))

Answer (score 0):

You can use group join

```
from e in employee
join d in deparment.Where(x => x.deptid == "D101") 
    on e.empdept equals d.dept into g
where e.employeeid == "E101" || g.Any()
select e;
```

That generates following SQL

```
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'E101'
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = 'D101'

SELECT *
FROM [employee] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[employeeid] = @p0) OR (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [deparment] AS [t1]
    WHERE ([t0].[empdept] = [t1].[dept]) AND ([t1].[deptid] = @p1)
    ))
```